# ArrayList in Jtable Column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm creating a Jtable, with only one column (month Column) and adding an arraylist in the column with the help of button.

the Arraylist contains name of months depending upon checked months.

my Problem is when i add array list the previous row also change.

I have no idea what is going on.

Here is my code for the problem

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Jtable extends JFrame {

    JTable table;
    JButton button;
    JPanel mp;

    DefaultTableModel model;

    JCheckBox chkJan;
    JCheckBox chkFeb;
    JCheckBox chkMarch;
    JCheckBox chkApril;
    JCheckBox chkMay;
    JCheckBox chkJun;
    JCheckBox chkJuly;
    JCheckBox chkAug;
    JCheckBox chkSep;
    JCheckBox chkOct;
    JCheckBox chkNov;
    JCheckBox chkDec;

    List<String> Months = null;

    public Jtable() {

        table = new JTable();
        button = new JButton("Add to Table");
        mp = new JPanel();
        Months = new ArrayList<>();

        chkJan = new JCheckBox("JAN");
        chkFeb = new JCheckBox("FEB");
        chkMarch = new JCheckBox("MARCH");
        chkApril = new JCheckBox("APRIL");
        chkMay = new JCheckBox("MAY");
        chkJun = new JCheckBox("JUN");
        chkJuly = new JCheckBox("JULY");
        chkAug = new JCheckBox("AUG");
        chkSep = new JCheckBox("SEP");
        chkOct = new JCheckBox("OCT");
        chkNov = new JCheckBox("NOV");
        chkDec = new JCheckBox("DEC");

        mp.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        mp.setSize(300, 200);

        mp.add(chkJan);
        mp.add(chkFeb);
        mp.add(chkMarch);
        mp.add(chkApril);
        mp.add(chkMay);
        mp.add(chkJun);
        mp.add(chkJuly);
        mp.add(chkAug);
        mp.add(chkSep);
        mp.add(chkOct);
        mp.add(chkNov);
        mp.add(chkDec);

        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        table.setModel(model);
        model.addColumn("Months");

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(mp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setSize(800, 600);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Month();
                Object[] row = {Months};

                model.addRow(row);
            }
        });

    }

    public void Month() {
        Months.removeAll(Months);
        if (chkJan.isSelected()) {
            Months.add("January");
        } else {
            Months.remove("January");
        }

        if (chkFeb.isSelected()) {
            Months.add("Febuary");
        } else {
            Months.remove("Febuary");
        }

        if (chkMarch.isSelected()) {
            Months.add("March");
        } else {
            Months.remove("March");
        }

        if (chkApril.isSelected()) {
            Months.add("April");
        } else {
            Months.remove("April");
        }

        if (chkMay.isSelected()) {
            Months.add("May");
        } else {
            Months.remove("May");
        }

        if (chkJun.isSelected()) {
            Months.add("Jun");
        } else {
            Months.remove("Jun");
        }

        if (chkJuly.isSelected()) {
            Months.add("July");
        } else {
            Months.remove("July");
        }

        if (chkAug.isSelected()) {
            Months.add("August");
        } else {
            Months.remove("August");
        }

        if (chkSep.isSelected()) {
            Months.add("September");
        } else {
            Months.remove("September");
        }

        if (chkOct.isSelected()) {
            Months.add("Octuber");
        } else {
            Months.remove("Octuber");
        }

        if (chkNov.isSelected()) {
            Months.add("November");
        } else {
            Months.remove("November");
        }

        if (chkDec.isSelected()) {
            Months.add("December");
        } else {
            Months.remove("December");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;

                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jtable.class
                    .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Jtable().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. None of your JCheckBox fields start with an upper case character, so why does the List? Be consistent!!! Also method names should not start with an upper case character. This is basic Java follow the conventions of the API and don't make up your own. Don't call your class `Jtable`. That is too close to the `JTable` class name. Be more descriptive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `Months` is global, what you want is a local variable. If you edit this variable somewhere, every object that is using it (like the rows or you table) will be reflect its changes.

You could move `Months` to somewhere inside your methods where you have only local access, something like this:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        model.addRow(Months());
    }
});
```

And then, modify your `Month` method:

```
public Object[] Month() {
    List<String> Months = new ArrayList<>();
    if (chkJan.isSelected()) {
        Months.add("January");
    } else ...
    ...
    return new Object[]{Months};
}
```

Another thing, is a good practice to name your variables in lowercase `Months` could be `months`, and name your methods to something more readable like `getSelectedMonths` and last, is confusing to name your class `Jtable` since there's another with a similar name (`JTable`).

**EDIT**

After checking again, I guess many of your code is redundant, you could remove and optimize since you only need what `Month` returns.

Comment: Thank a lot  its working ....My original form is big and have auto generated code by NetBeans. I cannot post the code here because of auto generate messy code. i write this short code to clearly specify my problem, thank you again for your quick reponse

Comment: But i sill don't understand how it is changing the previous row.??

Comment: (1+) that is you need to create a new `List` every time you click on the button and the `month()` method is invoked.

Comment: `But i sill don't understand how it is changing the previous row.??` - because you are just adding a "reference" to the List to the TableModel, not the actual data in the List. All your code does is change the data, but the reference is still the same, so you need to create a new instance of the LIst every time.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public void Month() {
        Months.removeAll(Months);
        ...
```

To:

```
public void Month() {
        Months = new ArrayList<>();
        ...
```

That way you are not modifying the Months that are already stored in the table.